# How can I shift elements around in my state vector according to a specific pattern?

Tags: quantum-state, gate-synthesis

Consider the statevector $|\psi_1\rangle=(a_0,...,a_{N-1})^T$.

My goal is to shift the elements around to end up with $|\psi_2\rangle=(a_{3N/4},...,a_{N-1},a_0,...a_{N/2},\vec{\phi})^T$ where $\vec{\phi}$ represents the remaining elements in any order.

My question is, what gate operations do I need to implement to perform this operation?

Comment: Hi, just to clarify. Are you asking how do I construct a circuit to implement a permutation of the amplitudes of $|\psi_1\rangle$? Essentially how to shuffle the coefficients of the basis elements?

Comment: If so I’ve written an answer that seems related. Its a bit thin on theoretical background currently (should probably update) https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/14636/how-do-i-construct-a-circuit-to-reshuffle-some-computational-basis-vectors/32741#32741

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In block notation, we can write $|\psi_1\rangle$ and $|\psi_2\rangle$ as $[A \quad B \quad C \quad D]^T$ and $[D \quad A \quad B \quad C ]^T$ respectively. So, it's a [cyclic permutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_permutation) of four elements which has the unitary:

$$\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}} 0&0&0&1 \\ 1&0&0&0 \\ 0&1&0&0 \\ 0&0&1&0 \end{array}} \right)$$
And by inspecting the *basis vectors* of each block, we can easily note that the unitary should by applied to the last two qubits.

The below Qiskit code demonstrates the solution:

```python
from qiskit.circuit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.quantum_info import Statevector
from qiskit.visualization import array_to_latex
import numpy as np

# Define ψ_1
n = 4
data = []
for m in range(2 ** n):
    data.append(m)

norm_factor = np.linalg.norm(data)

psi_1 = Statevector(data / norm_factor)

# Build the unitary
U = [
    [0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 0],
]

circ = QuantumCircuit(n)
circ.unitary(U, [n - 2, n - 1])

# Apply the operation
psi_2 = psi_1.evolve(circ)

# Display the result
display(array_to_latex(norm_factor * psi_1.data, max_size=2 ** n))
display(array_to_latex(norm_factor * psi_2.data, max_size=2 ** n))
```

The result

$$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 \\ \end{bmatrix}$$
$$\begin{bmatrix}12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 \\ \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: How did you figure this out? What was your thought process? I can easily construct a complete $2^n  \times 2^n$ unitary matrix that does this transformation, but how did you figure out it had to be identified on other qubits tensored with this on the last two qubits?

Comment: I edited my answer to add explanation about how I approached the problem.