The quantum complexity of implementing a permutation matrix
Suppose we are given a permutation matrix (which is unitary since it corresponds to a permutation of the basis), acting on a $2^n$-dimensional Hilbert space, which can be seen as a quantum system of $n$ qubits. Is there a way to find an efficient implementation of it with single- and two-qubit gates? Or at least estimate the required complexity.
A straightforward way would be to split it into transpositions and implement them. But the number of transpositions could be very high, an order of $2^n$. Is there a way to do it more efficiently?

I think this question might be related https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/14636/how-do-i-construct-a-circuit-to-reshuffle-some-computational-basis-vectors

In fact I should include the complexity in the answer

@Callum, yes, that's the same question. And ToffoliBox is implementing that, but how? Gray codes are used to implement transpositions, but as I noted, the number of transpositions could be very high.

Yeah good point. My answer is a bit thin on detail at present. I can edit it.

@DanyloY Would it be at least as difficult as (classical) logic synthesis? How is your permutation presented - with something like cycle notation on $2^n$ basis states? Or does it matter?  (Also you want to avoid CCNOT or any other three-qubit gate?)

@MarkSpinelli If true then I'd like to see a proof that we can't get a quantum advantage in this problem. The representation doesn't matter. What's matter is that we permuting the standard basis and not some exotic. CCNOT gate is not a problem since it adds only a constant multiplier to the overall complexity after an expansion into 2-qubit gates.

I think this should not be much easier than classical logic synthesis.  The complexity of (not necessarily reversible) logic synthesis is known to be $\sum_2^p$-complete, or likely even harder than being NP-complete assuming the Polynomial Hierarchy doesn't collapse.  Although there are many great heuristics that drive much of VLSI- and ASIC-design nowadays.
In particular, such a permutation can be thought of as a truth-table with $2^n$ rows, each with $n$ input bits and $n$ output bits. We can ignore the first $n-1$ output bits and consider just circuit optimization on the last bit, given the $2^n\times (n+1)$ truth-table. We can use our favorite logic synthesis technique such as Karnaugh maps or the Quine-McCluskey algorithm, etc., to optimize over the right set of gates.
It may be slightly easier, because we know that the last output bit is $0$ half of the time and $1$ half of the time (while Karnaugh maps and the QM algorithm are indifferent to this). But I suspect it's still likely $\sum_2^p$-hard to find the best circuit reversible circuit, even under the promise that the output bit of the Boolean formula is $0$ half of the time.
If reversible logic synthesis were computationally much easier than irreversible logic synthesis then it might make sense for even classical circuits to implement them.  But Googling "logic synthesis reversible circuits" generates a lot of hits.

I can see that classically it's a hard problem. After all, we have $(2^n)!$ different permutations. But are there permutations that can be implemented way faster using quantum gates instead of classical? For example, QFT is a square root of a permutation and we have a quantum advantage related to it.

@DanyloY I don’t know! If we have a (classical) permutation of order $n$ using $m$ (classical) gates, can we find a (classical) permutation of order $2n$ using $\log m$ quantum gates? The shortest distance between two points often goes through the complex plane…

Now I see the point of your previous question. You're asking if we can get a speedup in a (purely classical) permutation by using things like $\sqrt X$ or $\sqrt{\text{SWAP}}$ gates. It could still be difficult to find such a circuit (if it exists), which was the question that I answered, but if it does exist then there would be a motivation to find it!
